# Adding a listener to an array of elements, need unique arguments for function on each item

Tags: javascript, scope, listener

I have a bit of HTML generated by PHP in the format of:

```
<div class=zoomButton>
<input type=hidden name=zoomURL value=*different per instance*>
</div>
```

I am trying to attach a listener (imageZoom(event, url)) to each of the class "zoomButton" elements, but call it with different arguments for each instance.

i.e.

```
var zoomButtonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomButton');
for (i=0; i<zoomButtonArray.length; i++)
    {   
        var zoomURL = zoomButtonArray[i].children[0].value;
        zoomButtonArray[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function(){imageZoom(event,zoomURL);});
   }
```

however it seems that zoomURL is always the value of the very last element.  How can I change my code/approach so that the argument passed to the listener is the correct one, and not the last one in the "zoomButtonArray" array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the event listener in a closure:

```
function makeEventListenerForZoomURL(zoomURL) {
  return function(event) {
    imageZoom(event, zoomURL);
  }
}

var zoomButtonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomButton');
for (i=0; i<zoomButtonArray.length; i++)
{
  zoomButtonArray[i].addEventListener(
    "mousedown",
    makeEventListenerForZoomURL(zoomButtonArray[i].children[0].value)
  );
}
```

This can also be simplified using the ECMAScript5 `forEach`:

```
var zoomButtonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomButton');
zoomButtonArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(zoomButtonArray, 0);
zoomButtonArray.forEach(function(node) {
  node.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    imageZoom(event node.children[0].value);
  });
});
```

The reason is that each time the for loop executes a new function is created, this new scope references the variable `i` but `i` changes each time the loop iterates. So by the time the event listener runs it looks at the value of `i` only to find that it is the last value when the for loop ended. By using a closure described above the scope created is unique to each iteration of the loop so that when the event listener finally executes the value of the *wrapped* variable (`zoomURL` or `node` in the examples above) will not have changed.

Here is a good article explaining closures in for loops: http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=JavaScript_loop_closures

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation, working like a charm.  Included link is very illustrative.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing quotes around attributes. I just added quotes and the tested at jsFiddle (Fiddle link in comments) and it's working see to console in developer tool. it is iterating through each element as desired. [Console screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcrvx.png)